# Extract text between tags c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, tags

I have to make a function that reads all substrings between all tags of format: `<tag>sometext</tag>`. 'tag' can be any alphanumeric character, and user can enter as many different tags as he wants, but without nested tags. I have to use regex-es...
I made something that prints first substring between first tags, but I can't figure out how to automate function to work from start to end of user input string...
Thanks!

Comment: If it is an xml like structured open-close tag, could you consider XML De-serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the back reference:

```
<([^>]+)>([^<]*)</(\1)>
```

`(\1)` indicate that it must be the text contained in the first group.

I put `[^<]*` as content, but if you may have sub elements, you should use `.*`

Comment: `(\1)` is not necessary, `\1` is sufficient. With the round brackets, you're indicating that you want to save the match in another group (in this case, `\3`), which is not necessary, since you know it's already `\1`

Comment: yes sure, just an habbit to put all variable things into a group

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<[a-zA-Z0-9^>]>*(.*)</[[a-zA-Z0-9^>]*>
```

Comment: Assume you have a string like `"<a>hello<b></b>world</a>"`, your Regex will match `"<a>hello<b></b>world</a>"` , `"<b></b>world</a>"` and `"</b>world</a>"`

Comment: it has been mentioned in question that there will be no nested tags

Comment: I see, but I just found an error in your regex (you forgot to match the ending bracket for the tag-opener). `<[a-zA-Z0-9^>]*` should be `<[a-zA-Z0-9^>]*>` instead

Comment: @Nolanar is right, even if tags are not nested(can be one next other, you risk to return a result with a start tag which doesn't match the end tag.

Comment: Your regex doesn't make any sense. And it is going to fail to match correct if there are 2 instances of the tag